# PHP - better way of checking through variables one by one

Tags: php, variables

I have a php application where users upload specific images, and the number of images can be different per user. I have a variable set on startup as false for each image that i change to true once its done.

For example one user might have to upload 3 and have so far done 2 so:

```
$required = 3;
$houseImageStatus1 = true;
$houseImageStatus2 = true; 
$houseImageStatus3 = false;
```

Another then may have to upload 5 and have done them all:

```
$required = 5;
$houseImageStatus1 = true;
$houseImageStatus2 = true; 
$houseImageStatus3 = true;
$houseImageStatus4 = true;
$houseImageStatus5 = true;
```

I need to be able to check that all required images have been uploaded before continuing. At the moment i have a very long-winded and ugly way be doing:

```
if($required==3){
    if($houseImageStatus1==true && 
       $houseImageStatus2==true && 
       $houseImageStatus3==true){
       // allow continue
    }
    else {
        // pause
    }
}

if($required==5){
    if($houseImageStatus1==true && 
       $houseImageStatus2==true && 
       $houseImageStatus3==true && 
       $houseImageStatus4==true && 
       $houseImageStatus5==true){
       // allow continue
    }
    else {
        // pause
    }
}
```

Can i do the above but in a much shorter and cleaner way? Maybe in some sort of array and loop through them as a function?

Comment: Use an array, like a real programmer.  :)  (Why is this such a common problem, when the solution is so simple?)

Comment: How about 'some sort of array and loop through them...'

Comment: how about using a counter? increment it with each upload, check if it reaches the required amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the boolean values in an array, use `array_filter` to remove the `false` values and then check the array size against your variable `$required`:

```
$houseImageStatus = array();
$houseImageStatus[0] = true;
$houseImageStatus[1] = true; 
$houseImageStatus[2] = false;
// and so on

if(sizeof(array_filter($houseImageStatus)) == $required){
// everything is okay
}
else{
// something is wrong
}
```

Comment: this is the one i went with, thank you! Sorry for such a stupid and basic question - still learning

Answer (score 3):

Use arrays for this purposse:

```
$houseImageStatus[1] = true;
$houseImageStatus[2] = true; 
$houseImageStatus[3] = false;
```

and then check if all are true:

```
if (count(array_unique($houseImageStatus)) === 1 && $houseImageStatus[0] === true) {
    // here you go
} else {
    // nope
}
```

Comment: Probably shouldn't be quoting `'true'`.  :)

Comment: Thank you for spotting that.

Answer (score 1):

You Could use either:

1. Array and check for falses in array and by checking the index of array, You could determine the size (here you named it as ***$required***).

   ```
                                  OR
   ```
2. Using a counter which increments with each uploading of images....
   Use different counters with different users . You dont have to give seperate variables for each user.. You could use any existing user dependant variables like user_id or user_name..

Comment: in_array(); could be used to check whether any element in an array or not..
So using that it will be very easy for you..

Answer (score 0):

You can do array with all values set to false:

```
$houseimages = array();
$n = 5; // How many pictures
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) $houseimages[$i] = false; // Set all to false
```

And now, when user uploads one picture, just set $houseimages[0] = true; and so on.

Later just look through array and check if all values are true or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$required = 3;
$filled =0;
$houseImageStatus1 = true; $filled=$filled+1;

if ($required==$filled){//continue} else {//pause}
```

Comment: No need for nested `if`s.  Just check `if($required == $filled)`